# Javascript to refresh parent does not work with another script present

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to automatically refresh a parent window from a popup.

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

The script works fine when I close the window manually. The problem is when I use the following script to close the popup automatically.

```
<script>var daddy = window.self; 
daddy.opener = window.self;
daddy.close();</script>
```

If I close the window manually, the parent page refreshes and everything works fine. However, if I add the second script, to close the popup automatically, the parent page does not refresh, but the popup closes. I've tried changing the first script to body.onload and window.onload, but neither works. How can I get these two scripts to work together, or solve the problem in another way?

Comment: `daddy.opener = window.self;` you can't assign to window.opener (which is what your code is attempting to do) ... that code is basically ... `window.opener = window; window.close();`

Comment: Both scripts work fine independently as is.

Comment: yes, but your three lines to close the window can be simply `window.close()` - you've found the real issue, the fact that onunload doesn't always run when the window is closed - try `onbeforeunload` to avoid the timeout hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I found a solution. It seems that maybe the script to refresh doesn't have time to run when I add the script to automatically close the child. I added a 1 second delay in between the two scripts and everything works fine.

A user above provided a more eloquent solution. onbeforeunload fixes the issue in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot work because of this code

```
var daddy = window.self; 
daddy.opener = window.self;
```

when you do that you are trying to re-set the window.opener (to the popup), so your eventual call to

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

will not be calling `reload` in the opener, but reload in the popup.

So, why not just do

```
<script>close();</script>
```

in the popup?

Comment: When run alone the script correctly refreshed the parent page. There is only a problem when I use the script to close itself. Both scripts work fine on their own.